# ¿Cómo reportar a un usuario?

Tags: soporte, moderación, reportes, usuarios

Es raro ver usuarios "trolls" u otro adjetivo que aplique, pero, por ejemplo, durante las revisiones he visto "pocos" comentarios como respuestas, pero ni son respuestas ni comentarios.

No he vuelto a ver cómo esos usuarios generan contenido basura, pero así como se van, pueden venir otros.

Leyendo el post *"Votemos por contenido, no por personas"* se menciona a un usuario "con quien **por el momento no he tenido ningún tipo de interacción**" al parecer su forma de expresarse o interactuar en la comunidad no es la mejor.

Hace unos meses ví a un usuario que publicó preguntas de muy baja calidad y su respuesta "aunque no fue grosera" no era lo que esperaba, estuve buscando la manera de que "en su perfil" existiera un enlace que dijera *"reportar usuario"*, pero no lo encontré.

Sin entrar en detalles porque "de nuevo, no he tenido contacto con ese tipo de usuarios de manera tan personal (por decirlo así)", me ha llevado a preguntar:

¿Cómo reportar un usuario?

Comment: Se puede denunciar la violación del código de conducta a través de [Centro de ayuda: Contacta con nosotros](https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact) y en ella seleccionar que quieres denunciar una violación del código de conducta y luego describir la situación.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No se puede reportar a un usuario como tal.

Si quieres reportar su comportamiento, ve a cualquiera de sus publicaciones (preferentemente uno que muestre *ese* comportamiento) y repórtalo usando la opción *Se necesita la intervención de un moderador*.

Si ese usuario no tiene ninguna publicación, elige alguna publicación donde pueda estar presente y repórtarla usando la misma opción y detallando a qué usuario te refieres junto con una explicación de porqué crees que un moderador debe tomar acciones.